# Tengo el siguiente problema, cuando abro la ventana en la interfaz gráfica no se muestra que la cuenta regresiva esta en funcionamiento

Tags: tkinter, bucles, python-3.7

Adjunto el código debajo. En la parte de segundos se muestra la suma total de los segundos y no logro establecer que sean los 60 segundos.Luego no realizar la cuenta atras que tendía que hacer, existe alguna solución?. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
def countdown():
        global segundos
        if segundos > 0:
            se = segundos
            dias, se = divmod(se, 86400)
            horas, se = divmod(se, 3600)
            mins, se = divmod(se, 60)
            if dias < 100:
                h = '0' + str(dias)
            elif dias < 19:
                h = '00' + str(dias)
                se = segundos - (dias * 86400)
            if horas > 24:
                h = str(horas)
            elif horas <= 24:
                h = str(horas)
            elif horas < 432:
                h = '0' + str(horas)
                se = segundos - (horas * 3600)
            if mins > 59:
                m = str(mins)
            elif mins <= 59:
                m = str(mins)
            elif mins < 25920:
                m = '0' + str(mins)
            se = segundos - (mins * 60)
            s = str(se)
            if se < 10:
                s = '0' + str(se) 
            mensaje = f'  Restan {dias} dias, {horas:02d} horas, 
            {minutos:02d} minutos y {se:02d}
            segundos'
            timer_Label.config(textvariable = time)
            ventana.after(1000, countdown)
        elif segundos == 0:
            messagebox.showinfo(' Ya llego la hora! ')  
    time = StringVar()
    timer_Label = Label(ventana, font=('DS-Digital', 20))
    timer_Label.place(x=30, y=30)
    countdown()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón por la que no hay cuenta regresiva es ¡porque nunca restas 1 al contador de segundos!

Al margen de eso, el programa tiene otros errores por los que no llega siquiera a funcionar, más allá de que la cuenta no varíe. Son los siguientes:

1. Al final del programa tienes que poner `ventana.mainloop()` o de lo contrario el programa terminará inmediatamente tras ejecutar `countdown()`
2. El f-string que asignas a la variable `mensaje` está partido en dos líneas, lo que es un error. Posiblemente haya sido culpa del copy&paste y en tu código esté bien.
3. Ese mensaje que has creado no llegas a usarlo nunca. Te falta un `time.set(mensaje)`
4. Toda la parte previa en la que mediante muchos `if` añades ceros por la izquierda sobra, si vas a usar el f-string que mediante las opciones `:02d` etc ya indican que se realice ese relleno
5. La línea con `timer_Label.config(textvariable = time)` no necesita estar dentro del `contdown()`, puede estar en el programa principal.
6. El `elif segundos==0` debería ser un `else`. De ese modo te proteges también del hipotético caso en que `segundos` llegara a tomar valores negativos (aunque no debería suceder). Con tu `elif` ese caso no entraría y la ventana no se cerraría. Con el `else` en cambio sí.

Arreglando todas estas cosas el programa queda así:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, StringVar, Label, messagebox
ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Cuenta Regresiva")
ventana.resizable(0,0)
ventana.geometry("1000x750")
segundos = 1555000

def countdown():
    global segundos
    segundos -= 1
    if segundos > 0:
        se = segundos
        dias, se = divmod(se, 86400)
        horas, se = divmod(se, 3600)
        mins, se = divmod(se, 60)
        mensaje = f'  Restan {dias:03d} dias, {horas:02d} horas, {mins:02d} minutos y {se:02d} segundos'
        time.set(mensaje)
        ventana.after(1000, countdown)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Mensaje', 'Ya llego la hora, hay que irse !!! ')
        ventana.quit()

frame3 = Frame(ventana, width=150, height=400)
frame3.pack()
time = StringVar()
timer_Label = Label(ventana, font=('DS-Digital', 20))
timer_Label.place(x=30, y=30)
timer_Label.config(textvariable = time)
countdown()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mil gracias por la ayuda!, la agradezco mucho. no me dejo poner la otra parte del codigo pero si habia usar ventana.mainloop(). despues lo demas lo voy corrigiendo.

Comment: No hay de qué. Si te ha servido puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada.